# Is there a way to open a disk as a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, binary, disk

Can I open /dev/loop0 in order to binread some of the file?

this code

```
IO.binread("/dev/loop0", 64000, offset.to_i - 64000)
```

returns the error:

```
`binread': Invalid argument @ rb_io_seek - /dev/loop0 (Errno::EINVAL)
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it associated to some image file?

Comment: It is associated with a .dd file, however as i would like to extend functionality to actual disks. Reading from the dd, although it works is far from ideal

Comment: Yes, you can read a disk as a file in Ruby. Just read `/dev/sda1/` as root for example. `/dev/loop0/` isn't a disk though. Associated to an image file, it won't give you more information than the image file. If it's mounted somewhere, you can access the content of the image. I don't see the point in reading `/dev/loop0` directly, though.

Comment: I tried IO.binread("/dev/sda1", 64000, offset.to_i - 64000)  but got the same error mentioned above

Comment: Back to basics: does /dev/sda1/ exist? do you have the permission to read it? can you run `head /dev/sda1`? can you run `sudo head /dev/sda1`? how big is `offset`? can you run `IO.binread("/dev/sda1", 64)`?

Comment: Head and IO.binread("/dev/sda1", 64) both work. offset is the total number of bytes on the disk minus 64KiB then read a length of 64 KiB. This exists in a loop to read a disk backwards in chunks of 64KiB. 
So it seems to me its some issue with how much of the disk I'm reading and from where.   

So I think you have solved my issue, thank you for all your help

Comment: Are you running this as root? A normal user should not be able to read devices otherwise they would be able to circumvent the normal Linux file security.